# Are MicroSD card to USB bridges size limited?

Tags: usb, usb-storage, micro-sd-card

I'm looking to buy a MicroSD to USB converter and want to use it with a 32 gig MicroSD card.  Some online listings for these devices don't mention any size limits, others (for the same model device) say they work up to 16 gigs.

Is there any reason that a converter would implement a size restriction on the size of the card?  (I can't think why this would be the case, but then again I'm confused as to why they would be advertised with a limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 16 GB limit is indeed rather nonsensical.

However, depending on the SD version supported, there are other limits:

- SD: Up to 2 GB (unofficially 4 GB)
- SDHC: Up to 32 GB
- SDXC: Up to 2 TB

This information and further details are available on [Wikipedia's SD article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDHC#Overview).

A card's type is typically shown on its casing.

Comment: I received the unit, and indeed it works fine with a 32gig card.  Your confirmation and added information appears right on the money.